# Iterating over a row of a 2d matrix of vectors using an iterator in cpp

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Is there an iterator for this?

```
for (vector<string>:: const_iterator it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

this is for a regular matrix.

```
for (vector<vector<string>>:: const_iterator it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

would something like this work or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "2D matrix" is just a vector of vectors. When you iterate over it, each iterator points to a vector. This is hardly surprising. There is no reason to expect the iterator to an element of a vector to behave differently here.

In your case, you have to provide the code to stream a vector of string. This part won't work

```
cout << *it << endl;
```

in your second example because there is no `ostream& operator<<` for an `std::vector<std::string>`.

Also note that you are not allowed to overload `std` namespace operators for standard library types unless explicitly allowed to do so, but you can provide a function to do it:

```
void streamStuff(std::ostream& o, const std::vector<std::string>>& v)
{
  for (const auto& s : v)
    o << s << " ";
}
```

then

```
for (vector<vector<string>>::const_iterator it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it)
{
    streamStuff(std::cout, *it);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: @OnTheFly you don't have a 2D matrix, you have a vector of vectors. A vector of vectors is a vector. And it contains more vectors.

Comment: what if you just want to put a bunch of string into a vector, one vector after another?

Comment: @OnTheFly what of it? Just do it? Better clarify what you are asking.